# Python3: Thread still alive after joined

Tags: python, multithreading

This my code

```
def timeout(seconds_before_timeout):
    def deco(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            res = [
                Exception("function [%s] timeout [%s seconds] exceeded!"
                          % (func.__name__, seconds_before_timeout))
            ]
            def new_func():
                try:
                    res[0] = func(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as ex:
                    res[0] = ex
            thread = Thread(target=new_func)
            thread.daemon = True
            try:
                thread.start()
                thread.join(seconds_before_timeout)
            except Exception as ex:
                print("error starting thread")
                raise ex
            ret = res[0]
            if isinstance(ret, BaseException):
                raise ret
            return ret
        return wrapper
    return deco
```

And timeout function i used for:

```
@timeout(2)
def listen_for_a_new_campaign(self):
    """
    Start listening for new campaign in list_campaign queue
    """
    while True:
        try:
            for method_frame, properties, body \
                    in self.obj_requester_channel.consume(LIST_CAMPAIGN_QUEUE):
                body_dict = literal_eval(body.decode("utf-8"))

                message_number = body_dict["Msg_Count"]

                n_message = min(message_number, BATCH_SIZE)
                identify(n_message)
                a_request = {
                    "campaign_request": body_dict,
                    "campaign_ack" : method_frame.delivery_tag,
                    "n_message" : n_message
                }
                identify(a_request)
                return a_request
                # Acknowledge the message
            n_requeued_messages = self.obj_requester_channel.cancel()
            print("Requeued %i messages" % n_requeued_messages)
            break
        except pika.exceptions.ConnectionWrongStateError:
            print("Create connection ...")
            self.create_connection()
            continue
        except pika.exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError:
            print("Create connection ...")
            self.create_connection()
            self.obj_requester_channel = self.obj_connection.channel()
            self.obj_requester_channel.queue_declare(queue=LIST_CAMPAIGN_QUEUE)
            self.obj_campaign_channel = self.obj_connection.channel()
            continue
```

When I run my program, I checked all process by htop and below is result, all thread is alive:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong with that.
I run this code on my laptop everything was OK, but when I deploy them to EC2 instance I found that problems.
Help me!!

Comment: `join()` will not kill the thread if it does not terminate within the timeout. Is your intention to kill the thread if it does not return within the timeout?

Comment: yes,because I used some AWS services, so I want to renew credentials aws

Comment: And I don't know why my program run on my local pc ok then run on EC2 that didn't work

Comment: I would remove the `timeout` decorator all together, you don't need to spawn threads for this. I would also remove the while loop from this method and handle those errors in the calling method

Comment: I want to listen to a queue Rabbitmq each 2s. If I remove the while loop I can't listen new request